# Implementing diffuse per-vertex shader, not working

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am implementing a diffuse per-vertex shader from the OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook, but have modified slightly in order to fit my project.

This is my vertex shader code:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexCoord;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform vec4 position; // Light position, initalized to vec4(100, 100, 100, 1)
uniform vec3 diffuseReflectivity; // Initialized to vec3(0.8, 0.2, 0.7)
uniform vec3 sourceIntensity; // Initialized to vec3(0.9, 1, 0.3)

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

out vec3 LightIntensity;

void main(void) {
    // model should be the normalMatrix here in case that
    // non-uniform scaling has been applied.
    vec3 tnorm = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(vertexNormal, 0.0)));

    // Convert to eye/camera space
    vec4 eyeCoordsLightPos = view * model * position;
    vec4 eyeCoords = view * model * vertexCoord;
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(eyeCoordsLightPos - eyeCoords));

    // Diffuse shading equation
    LightIntensity = sourceIntensity * diffuseReflectivity * max(dot(s,tnorm), 0.0);

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vertexCoord;
}
```

And this is my fragment shader:

```
in vec3 LightIntensity;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main(){
    FragColor = vec4(LightIntensity, 1.0);
}
```

I am rendering a box, and I have values for all normals. However the box is just black.
Assuming my uniforms are set correctly on rendering, is there anything obviously wrong with my shader code?

*What I have changed compared to the code from the book is I use the model matrix as a normal matrix and I have my light position passed in model space, but convert it to camera space in the shader.*

Image of rendering, do not be confused by the shaded background which is a texture:
[image: Image of rendering, do not be confused by the shaded background which is a texture.]

Picture when rendering with `FragColor = vec4(f_vertexNormal, 1.0);` in fragment shader:
[image]

Updated code with tnorm in eye space suggestion:

```
void main(void) {
    // model should be the normalMatrix here in case that
    // non-uniform scaling has been applied.
    vec3 tnorm = normalize(vec3(model * vec4(vertexNormal, 0.0)));

    // Convert to eye/camera space
    vec3 eyeTnorm = vec3(view * vec4(tnorm, 0.0));
    vec4 eyeCoordsLightPos = view * position;
    vec4 eyeCoords = view * model * vertexCoord;
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(eyeCoordsLightPos - eyeCoords));

    // Diffuse shading equation
    LightIntensity = sourceIntensity * diffuseReflectivity * max(dot(s,eyeTnorm), 0.0);

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vertexCoord;
    f_vertexNormal = vertexNormal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting some intermediate signals? If you color the box with `s` is it black? If you color the box with `vertexNormal` is it black? Also it seems a little weird to me that you would transform the light position by the model matrix, though I don't think that would necessarily cause it to not function.

Comment: added a picture where I use the vertexnormal as color. Looks correct to me. I agree with the model matrix, it should not be necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition with my comment above, you're `dot`-ing a world space vector `tnorm` with an eye space vector `s`. You should only dot vectors in the same space. So you might want to consider transforming `tnorm` to eye space as well.

Comment: I suppose you mean tnorm not tvec?
This is how it comes in the book:
`vec3 tnorm = normalize(NormalMatrix * VertexNormal)`

Comment: Added a new code snippet where I transform the tnorm to eye space. Still the same black result.

Comment: Yes, you're right I mean `tnorm`, sorry. In the book I assume that NormalMatrix is a matrix that transform the normal into eye space, similar to the modelview matrix. In your case though normalMatrix is just transforming into world space.

Comment: @toeplitz *Assuming my uniforms are set correctly on rendering* Have you actually verified this? That's a big assumption to make.

Comment: What about the updated code where I transform tnorm to eye space?

Comment: I haven't really looked at it, though I'm assuming you did it correctly. I was just trying to think of what else could be the problem.

Comment: I hardcoded the uniform variables in the shader now. Seems like that was actually the problem. I see that when I transform tnorm to eye space the shading stays fixed however I view the object. When I do not transform the tnorm to eye space the shading changes as I move aroudn the object, which is wrong ?